# Angular js + ui codemirror jasmine test case

Tags: node.js, angularjs, jasmine

I have used `ui.codemirror` directive in my application.I have one functionality of in which If user clicks on any node of a tree.That node should be added to `textarea.Codemirror` is used to highlight that text if it's a keyword.

My controller function which does that task is below

```
 $scope.addTextToTextArea = function(node) {
        node = JSON.parse(node);
        $scope.testObj+= node.displayName + ',';
        _docObject.setValue($scope.testObj);
    };
```

I have written  jasmine test case to test this functionality.

```
it('should add text to query',inject(function(){
    var node='{"id":"1","displayName":"testColumn","collapsed":false,"childColumn":[]}';
    scope.addTextToTextArea (node);
    expect(scope.testObj).toBeDefined();
    expect(scope.testObj).toEqual('testColumn');
}));
```

But the problem  is when grunt task is executing this.I am getting error like

> Controller:: should add text to query: failed 
>   TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating
>   '_docObject.setValue')

Anyone have any idea? how to solve that?

I have created one `MockObject` for `_docObject` but I don't know how to use it.